# Cat Command without Object In Container Template

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

i'm interested with jenkins dynamic slave in kubernetes with this repo

https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-plugin

I know cat use to be followed by object, but in this template it just cat without object behind.

So what's the function of the "cat" command below?

```
def label = "mypod-${UUID.randomUUID().toString()}"
podTemplate(label: label, containers: [
    containerTemplate(name: 'maven', image: 'maven:3.3.9-jdk-8-alpine', ttyEnabled: true, **command: 'cat'**),
    containerTemplate(name: 'golang', image: 'golang:1.8.0', ttyEnabled: true, **command: 'cat'**)
  ]) {
```

______Found the answer by myself________

For you all that misunderstand and you all that downvote my question

So, the cat on that container template, is to keep the container running forever, so the container won't be recreated again when the container has been created

Comment: see https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin#constraints

"Other containers must run a long running process, so the container does not exit. If the default entrypoint or command just runs something and exit then it should be overridden with something like cat with ttyEnabled: true."

Answer (score 0):

That's the command that's executed. if you don't know what the cat command does, here's some info: http://www.linfo.org/cat.html (it's most commonly used to display files).

In the above context it's used to prove the concept of running commands in another container by displaying the piped stream.